# Simple pendulum: why is $-\frac{a_{\theta}}{l}=\theta''$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

Been stuck on the last equation below forever. Why is $-\frac{a_{\theta}}{l}=\theta''$?

[image]

Comment: The tangential acceleration divided by the length is the second time derivative of the angle.

Comment: Isn't that explained in the paragraphs preceeding your equations?

Comment: No, the author assumed I knew $a=l\alpha$--Took me a minute to see

Answer (score 1):

Evidently, you see that there is not radial acceleration. The only accelerations there are the ones of a circular movement. Those are

- Angular acceleration $\alpha$, also called $\theta''$ because it is the
  second derivative of the angle.
- The linear acceleration, related to the previous by  $a=l \alpha$
- and finally the normal acceleration, for which you don't care, as it
  is in the radial direction. It is compensated by the tension.

So the thing is only remembering that $a = l \alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Establish a coordinate system with z pointing upwards, y pointing to the right, and x pointing out of the page. In order to get the equation of motion of the pendulum, we have to apply the angular momentum principle (AMP) with respect to the hinge point (let's call it B) since it does not involve the forces $\vec{F_1}, \vec{F_2}$:   $$ \dot{\vec{H_B}} + \vec{v_B}\times\vec{P}= \vec{M_B}$$ The overall torque $M_B$ about B is $$ \vec{M_B}=(-m\,g\,l\,\sin\theta)\vec{e}_x $$ The linear momentum of the pendulum mass is $$\vec{P}=m\vec{v}=m\dot{\vec{r}}=m(l\,\cos\theta\,\dot{\theta}\,\vec{e}_y+l\,\sin\theta\,\dot{\theta}\,\vec{e}_z)$$ with the position vector $\vec{r}=l\sin\theta e_y-l\cos\theta e_z$ obtained from the geometry of the problem. Next, we calculate the angular momentum $$\vec{H_B}=\vec{\rho_B}\times\vec{P}=m(l^2\cos^2\theta\dot\theta+l^2\sin^2\theta\dot\theta)=ml^2\dot{\theta}e_x$$ where $\rho_B=\vec{r}$.
Since $v_B=0$, we can neglect the middle term of the AMP. Taking the derivative of the angular momentum and equating it to the moment about B, we get $$\frac{d}{dt}ml^2\dot\theta=-mgl\sin\theta$$ Finally, we get the result $$\ddot{\theta}=-\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta$$